# How to sort and group an list of dictionaries in right way in Python

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an list of dict in Python as follows:

```
options = [
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Air conditioning'}, 
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Air suspension'}, 
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Cruise control'}, 
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Leather interior'}, 
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Parking assist system camera'},
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Parking assist system sensors rear'},
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Power steering'}, 
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Seat heating'}, 
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Sunroof'}, 
  {'group_priority': 3, 'group': u'Entertainment', 'name': u'Bluetooth'}, 
  {'group_priority': 3, 'group': u'Entertainment', 'name': u'MP3'}, 
  {'group_priority': 3, 'group': u'Entertainment', 'name': u'Navigation system'}, 
  {'group_priority': 4, 'group': u'Extra', 'name': u'Alloy wheels'}, 
  {'group_priority': 4, 'group': u'Extra', 'name': u'Trailer hitch'}, 
  {'group_priority': 4, 'group': u'Extra', 'name': u'Winter tyres'}, 
  {'group_priority': 4, 'group': u'Security', 'name': u'Xenon headlights'}]
```

I want to order it by `group_priority` and group it by `group` and show it in Django template/

What I have tried:

```
options_grouped_dict = {}
for item in options_grouped:
    options_grouped_dict.setdefault(item['group'], []).append(item['name'])
```

And then in Django template:

```
{% for key, values in car.options_grouped.items %}
    <div>
        <div><strong>{{key}}</strong></div>
        {% for option in values %}
            <div>
                {% if option|length > 31 %}
                    {{ option|truncatechars:34 }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ option }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But it isn't ordered by `group_priority`. I get group `security` on first place instead of group `Comfort`

Any advice?

Comment: Your examples variable names are in shables :o) - they do not fit together. Why are you feeding your ungroupd dict in? `{% for key, values in car.options_grouped.items %}` ==> `{% for key, values in car.options_grouped_dict.items %}`

Comment: I send in the context `car['options_grouped'] = options_grouped_dict `

Comment: "I want to order it by group_priority and group it by group" What does this mean? Do you want to sort by group AND group_priority? Which has precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it using Django's [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).

The options list is as follows:

```
options = [
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Air conditioning'}, 
  {'group_priority': 2, 'group': u'Comfort', 'name': u'Air suspension'},  
  {'group_priority': 3, 'group': u'Entertainment', 'name': u'Bluetooth'}, 
  {'group_priority': 3, 'group': u'Entertainment', 'name': u'MP3'}, 
  {'group_priority': 3, 'group': u'Entertainment', 'name': u'Navigation system'}, 
  {'group_priority': 4, 'group': u'Extra', 'name': u'Alloy wheels'}, 
  {'group_priority': 4, 'group': u'Extra', 'name': u'Trailer hitch'},  
  {'group_priority': 4, 'group': u'Security', 'name': u'Xenon headlights'}]
```

And I have passed it (`options`) to the template as follows `car['options_grouped'] = options`

And then in the template I did as follows:

```
{% regroup car.options_grouped by group as groups %}
{% for group in groups %}
  <div>{{ group.grouper }}</div>
  {% for option in group.list %}
    <div> {{ option.name }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an orderedDict with dicts grouped by `group` and ordered by `group_priority`this should work:

```
#grouping in Dict with group as key and list of dict as value:    
grouped_dict={}
for option in options:
    if option['group'] in grouped_dict.keys():
        grouped_dict[option['group']].append(option)
    else:
        grouped_dict[option['group']] = [option]

#sorting by group_priority
ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(grouped_dict.items(), key=lambda t:t[1][0].get('group_priority')))

print(ordered)
```